# MySQL: ERROR 1072 (42000) at line.. Key column UserID doesn't exist in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, key, exists

I am trying to make simple database with 2 tables, first for user information, and second for their uploads, because it's project for faculty, I have some assignments... And one is to use foreign key.

But I can't figure out how to do that, when I do it with phpMyAdmin everything is working just fine, but when I export it and put it on my server I have some errors; please help me.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `korisnici` (
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `telefon` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slike` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `file_path` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `naslov` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `adresa` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `opis` varchar(1200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `datum` date NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `UserID` (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


ALTER TABLE `slike`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `slike_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `korisnici` (`UserID`);
```

ERRORS:

> ERROR 1072 (42000) at line 77: Key column 'UserID' doesn't exist in table

I would appreciate if someone could fix my code and explain.

EDIT new error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 42: Unknown column 'UserID' in 'field list'

Again when I insert something:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `korisnici` (
  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `telefon` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `korisnici` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `telefon`) VALUES('Aleksa2', 'c4b4d0dea25b6f2f38fef63330ea15c8', 'sss@gmail.com', '0649999999');

INSERT INTO `korisnici` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `telefon`) VALUES('Aleksa123', 'a4b4d0dea25b6f2f38fef63330ea15c8', 'aaaa@gmail.com', '0649999999');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slike` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `file_path` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `naslov` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `adresa` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `opis` varchar(1200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `datum` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `USERNAME_ID` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `slike` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `type`, `file_path`, `username`, `naslov`, `adresa`, `opis`, `datum`) VALUES(15, '4eb40ffebd3fbec4b1acf34a4fe8cb2d.png', 43395, 'image/png', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/data/localweb/images/4eb40ffebd3fbec4b1acf34a4fe8cb2d.png', 'Aleksa123', 'asdasdasd', 'dadasdas', 'Opisite problem u najvise 1200 karaktera.', '2014-09-05');
INSERT INTO `slike` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `type`, `file_path`, `username`, `naslov`, `adresa`, `opis`, `datum`) VALUES(16, '92bc0821619c053c503694666f2717ee.png', 32461, 'image/png', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/data/localweb/images/92bc0821619c053c503694666f2717ee.png', 'Aleksa123', 'dadasdasdas', 'dadasdasdasdasdas', 'Opisite problem u najvise 12dasdasdasdas00 karaktera.', '2014-09-05');
INSERT INTO `slike` (`id`, `name`, `size`, `type`, `file_path`, `username`, `naslov`, `adresa`, `opis`, `datum`) VALUES(17, '89d0507bf3ed3f492647b7fd2f39047a.png', 162203, 'image/png', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/data/localweb/images/89d0507bf3ed3f492647b7fd2f39047a.png', 'Aleksa123', '1111111111111a', 'dasdasdasda', 'Opisite problsdasdasdasdasaem u najvise 1200 karaktera.', '2014-09-05');

ALTER TABLE `slike`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `slike_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `korisnici` (`username`);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Care to share what errors you are getting?

Comment: ERROR 1072 (42000) at line 77: Key column 'UserID' doesn't exist in table

Comment: The code you have in the question runs fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f73ae.

Comment: I'm going to kill myself because server where i need to upload *.sql say that i have error :(

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: maybe now someone know why i have error? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1 i dont have tabular output here now...